# My Bools Aren't working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a "Battleship" like game. Most of my board is supposed to be "missed" tiles, and only a few are supposed to be tiles with submarines on them for a "hit". The problem is that whenever I run my program, I cannot tell if it is ignoring my bool or if it isn't understanding what I coded, because everything I click is a "hit".

```
var cellClick=function(clicked)
{
    var cell=clicked.target;

    if(! cell.isEmpty) return;

    if(cell.isSub=false)
        {

            cell.style.backgroundImage='url("missed.png")';
            cell.style.backgroundSize='constrain';


        }
    else
        {
            cell.style.backgroundImage='url("hit.png")';
            cell.style.backgroundSize='constrain';
            cell.exploded=true;

        }

    cell.isEmpty=false;
    console.log('click');

};

var waterCell=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];

for(var row=0;row<10;row++)
    {
        for(var column=0;column<10;column++)
            {
                waterCell[row][column]=document.createElement("div");
                waterCell[row][column].style.width='10%';
                waterCell[row][column].style.height='10%';
                waterCell[row][column].style.position='absolute';
                waterCell[row][column].style.left=(column*10)+'%';
                waterCell[row][column].style.top=(row*10)+'%';
                waterCell[row][column].style.backgroundImage='url("water_cell.jpg")';
                waterCell[row][column].style.backgroundSize='contain';
                gameBoard.appendChild(waterCell[row][column]);

                waterCell[row][column].row=row;
                waterCell[row][column].column=column;
                waterCell[row][column].isEmpty=true;
                waterCell[row][column].isSub=false;
                waterCell[row][column].exploded=false;


            }
    }
//trying to make random subs
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        row=Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        column=Math.round(Math.random()*10);
        waterCell[row][column].isSub=true;
    }






gameBoard.addEventListener('click',cellClick,false);
```

Comment: `cell.isSub=false` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: @charlietfl I am aware that it is an event object. My teacher used this method to obtain specific information on divs that were clicked due to the click event. Most of my code relating to the event object are based on what he did in class but modified. Does it's use look wrong?  Also, do you mean that I have given to much code or that the code looks full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
if(cell.isSub=false) {
```

is assigning false to the property `isSub` of `cell`. The assignment's result is then tested by `if`, which is `false`. That's why the condition is never met and the `else`-branch is processed. Obviously, your intention was

```
if(cell.isSub==false) {
```

Maybe try swapping the branches of `if` statement and test for truthy value in `cell.isSub` instead making the code simpler:

```
if ( cell.isSub ) {
  // it's a hit
} else {
  // it's a miss
}
```

If you require to keep this order of branches testing for falsy values can be simplified as well by using negation operator:

```
if ( !cell.isSub ) {
  // it's a miss
} else {
  // it's a hit
}
```

One last tip: don't set custom properties of a DOM element as those perform poorly. Even worse, they are perfect soil for memory leakages when putting Javascript objects or functions. Thus, keep the two worlds - your Javascript and your HTML/DOM - as separated as possible and train yourself not to put additional data into Javascript-representations of objects managed in context of DOM. Use a separate description in pure Javascript (e.g. two-dimensional array) for tracking position of your subs and create a DOM representing that internal data set, only.

Comment: Also note that there is a big difference between [`==` (Equality) and `===` (Identity)](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm). Here `===` is actually more fitting.

Comment: Thank you so much! I misunderstood and thought that if it was a boolean it would act odd if you used = instead of ==. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SourceOverflow Oh I see. I haven't ever known how or when to use `===`. Thank you!

Comment: @cepharum or @SourceOverflow Would you know how to fix my next problem? I can't seem to get my game to "win". I think it has something to do with the line where I try to change my `youWon` to `true`, but I can't seem to figure it out.
    `var youWon=false;
    
     if(waterCell[cell.row][cell.column].exploded==true && waterCell[cell.row][cell.column].exploded == 9)
    {
        youWon=true;
    }`

Comment: how should `waterCell[cell.row][cell.column]` be both `true` and `9` at the same time? Please put some effort in yourself before asking here.

Comment: @SourceOverflow I have been putting effort into this for a very long time. I am only a beginner programmer. I am trying to explain to the computer that once 9 of the 10 submarines have been clicked (and changed to `exploded=true`), then `youWon` should be changed to `true`. I have tried several combinations, but I can't figure out how to write it in a way that the computer understands me.

Comment: Then you have learned in the wrong way. There are different variable types: Boolean, Integer, Character, String, float etc. and then some composite ones like arrays, structs etc. One variable can only ever be of one type. In this case you need another variable to count the number of ships.

Comment: Also, **you never explain something to a computer**, since he will never understand you, you **tell him exactly what to do**. This may sound like nitpicking, but is actually a very different mindset.

Comment: As advised by SourceOverflow your approach suffers from severe misunderstandings. You need a different algorithm for what you are intended to do. It isn't sufficient to write sth that sounds like what you want, but think in very essentials steps you would require to achieve this aim yourself. If you check a single exploded marker you don't know the number of all such markers instantly, too, but need to count all such markers: `var youWon = waterCell.reduce( function( count, row ) { return row.reduce( function( count, cell ) { return cell.exploded ? count + 1 : count; }, count ) }, 0 ) >= 9;`